# How to edit and read the header of a MP3 file before encrypting it in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, mp3

I am encrypting an MP3 file into another format, what i want is, i should be able to write the header of the new format file. And i want to save the duration of the song in the header of the new format file. As the new file will be in encrypted format, so i want to write the duration in the header. So later on if i need the duration of the encrypted song file, i will just read the header instead of decrypting the whole file.

I am writing the code of my mp3 encryption technique.

```
public static void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
       {

           try
           {
               string password = @"myKey123"; // Your Key Here
               UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
               byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

               string cryptFile = outputFile;
               FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

               RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

               CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                   RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                   CryptoStreamMode.Write);

               FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

               int data;
               while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                   cs.WriteByte((byte)data);


               fsIn.Close();
               cs.Close();
               fsCrypt.Close();
           }
           catch
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Encryption failed!", "Error");
           }
       }
```

Comment: You need to use some MP3 library for .NET to parse the header. Or write your own. Also, don't read and write the data byte-by-byte - read a bunch of bytes (say, 4 kiB) to a buffer, and write it all at once. Or, if you've got .NET 4, use `Stream.CopyTo` to do the work for you.

Comment: any library link or any sample code?

Comment: Parsing the MP3 headers is quite easy. Search Google for `read mp3 header c#` or just write your own - the format is well documented.

Comment: check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6760/MP-header-reader

Comment: Is this possible to corrupt an MP3 file and then decorrupt the file, what i want is my file should be played in my player only.